# Da para apresentar textos no APP pelas strings?

Tags: android

estou criando um APP para listar as linhas de ônibus e quando clicar em uma linha, abrirá a informação dos horários da mesma linha. Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar estas Strings diretamente no APP??e, se sim, isso valeria à pena?? Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Você quer fazer isso pra não ter que buscar de um servidor na Internet?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pois eu gostaria que este APP funcionasse offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os dados são fixos você pode armazenar em uma base de dados sqlite, e apresentar ao usuário.

Agora, se os dados são dinâmicos, e fornecidos por um web-service, e você precisa que seja off-line, você deve atualizar a sua base de dados periodicamente, seja usando um arquivo, que você gerar e distribuir para as APPs, de alguma forma, ou fazendo com que elas consultem o WS ou um WS que você crie, periódicamente.

Minha opinião pessoal é de que pode valer a pena, pois linhas de ônibus não mudam todo dia. Eu colocaria uma recomendação de atualização no APP, dizendo que os dados estão desatualizados, e quando isso acontece, ele precisa consultaro WS para se atualizar, sendo isso opcional.

Pense que o usuário espera sempre pelo mais simples, se ele não precisar fazer nada, melhor para ele.

Comment: Muito obrigado.